# Jquery AutoComplete Post Key

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am having a right manic day trying to figure out how to post the key not the value of a input field.

**Jquery**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "{{URL('/autocomplete')}}",
            data: {
                autocomplete: this.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data[0]['label']);
                  response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.id
                    };
                }));
            },
            //This does not get  picked up? 
            select: function(event, ui){
                alert('this is not firing on select?');
                jQuery('#hidden').val(ui.item.value);
            }

        });
    },
});
```

I have updated code, still i cant get the key pushed to the hidden field on select.

**Live Preview ( type Stoke in location search )** 
http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~hospita2/crawler/public/index.php/search

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you. This is an autocomplete input, how do you want to use key instead on the value ?

Comment: Well I have a hidden field underneath the input I was going to put the key into that but I cant get it to work.

Comment: In your AJAX success, try `value: item.value` instead of `value: item.id`.

Comment: This works but I dont want it to say an actually number on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "{{URL('/autocomplete')}}",
            data: {
                autocomplete: this.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                  response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.label,
                        key: item.id
                    };
                }));
            },


        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
          console.log('something selected');
          jQuery('#hidden').val(ui.item.key);

          //jQuery('input[name="autocomplete"]').val(ui.item.label);

          jQuery('#autocomplete').attr({
            value: ui.item.label
          });

          console.log(ui.item.label);
          console.log(jQuery('input[name="autocomplete"]').val() + "this is the result of above");
    }
});


});
```